# Enabling SSL for Vhost on Ubuntu 14.04 / Apache2

Tags: apache, ssl

I'm trying to enable SSL on a site that I have on my Ubuntu Server. I've found just about the same few commands everywhere on the internet and it seems really straight forward but for some reason I can't seem to get it right.

Here's my steps (all are done as root/with sudo privileges).

Enable the SSL Module

```
a2enmod ssl
```

Create a director for my keys that Apache and The user/site owner have privilege to

```
sudo mkdir /etc/apache2/ssl
```

Make the needed keys with detailed names of the domain they belong to

```
sudo openssl req -x509 -nodes -days 365 -newkey rsa:2048 \
      -keyout /etc/apache2/ssl/example.key -out /etc/apache2/ssl/example.crt
```

I have an existing .conf file made for this site like so:

(And I also have my /home directory set to be a web directory)

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
       DocumentRoot /home/user
       <Directory /home/user>
               AllowOverride All
       </Directory>
       ServerName example.com
       ServerAlias www.example.com
       ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/example.com.error.log
       CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/example.com.access.log common
       AddType application/x-httpd-php .php
       <Files 'xmlrpc.php'>
               Order Allow,Deny
               deny from all
       </Files>
</VirtualHost>
```

I tried adding, replacing, placing before/after with the following .conf file and could not get the https://example.com to work. (The additional lines I added in were suggested from digital ocean's tutorial found here: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-create-a-ssl-certificate-on-apache-for-ubuntu-14-04

```
<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
    <VirtualHost *:443>
           DocumentRoot /home/user
           <Directory /home/user>
                   AllowOverride All
           </Directory>
           ServerName example.com
           ServerAlias www.example.com

            SSLEngine on
            SSLCertificateFile /etc/apache2/ssl/example.crt
            SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/apache2/ssl/example.key
            <FilesMatch "\.(cgi|shtml|phtml|php)$">
                    SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
            </FilesMatch>
            <Directory /usr/lib/cgi-bin>
                    SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
            </Directory>
            BrowserMatch "MSIE [2-6]" \
                    nokeepalive ssl-unclean-shutdown \
                    downgrade-1.0 force-response-1.0
            BrowserMatch "MSIE [17-9]" ssl-unclean-shutdown

           ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/example.com.error.log
           CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/example.com.access.log common
           AddType application/x-httpd-php .php
           <Files 'xmlrpc.php'>
                   Order Allow,Deny
                   deny from all
           </Files>
    </VirtualHost>
</IfModule>
```

The site is previously enabled so I didn't have to run the a2ensite command, although I did to make sure and the site was enabled. I then restarted apache

```
service apache2 restart
```

and went to https://example.com and had no luck with my SSL.

I realize that the tutorial I'm following is updating the default Apache file and I'm attempting to create another virtual host so it differs a little, but I'm simply just creating an extra vhost, I imagine it would work exactly the same as adding an extra .conf file.

The site runs great without SSL, so it makes sense that my Apache configuration would be the culprit here, I just can't seem to figure out exactly where I'm making a mistake.

Comment: I assume you have a `Listen 443` and possibly a `NameVirtualHost *:443` elsewhere in the configuration? (Also, what's "no luck with your SSL"? Does it complain about the certificate, does it simply not give you any connection at all?)

Comment: Do the server logs give you any clue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was unaware the certificate was self signed and I would have to authorize the certificate within my browser.

There is an awesome tool that will handle all SSL configurations for you that I would highly recommend - check it out!

https://certbot.eff.org/

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the code you posted is from default-ssl.conf, try this:

```
a2dissite default-ssl.conf
```

then

```
a2ensite default-ssl.conf
```

then

```
service apache2 reload
```